# RabbitMQ on VM cloned from an OS image fails to start, possibly due to node name

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to create a "golden" OS image (not container) to re-use when creating machines.

when I try to start Rabbit windows service on a cloned VM, I get

`[error] <0.305.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.305.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no match of right hand value noport in rabbit_networking:record_distribution_listener/0 line 282 in application_master:init/4 line 138`

It feels like there is some config somewhere regarding the node name, which no longer matches on the cloned machine, but I cannot see where that is.

This is Windows 2012.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever reporting an issue with RabbitMQ please always include the version of RabbitMQ and Erlang that you are using.

The failure is happening [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.7.8/src/rabbit_networking.erl#L282), which suggests a host name issue. Run the `RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir)` start menu item, and do the following:

```
.\rabbitmq-service.bat stop
.\rabbitmq-service.bat remove
.\rabbitmq-service.bat install
.\rabbitmq-service.bat start
```

When the Windows service that runs RabbitMQ is installed the host name is kept in the registry key that holds configuration for the service (`HKLM/SOFTWARE/Ericsson/Erlang/ErlSrv/1.1/RabbitMQ/SName`). Re-installing the service will update the node name.